# Amend the above Promela model with a mechanism for corrupting messages

Tags: promela

I'm studying for the final exam in system validation and this question was in last exam paper. I need help to solve it.

Intuitively, sender sends the squares of the first five non-negative integers to two receiver processes. Each number is sent only once, and the choice of receiver to which it is sent is random.
a) Suppose that the channels can corrupt messages. Amend the above Promela model with a mechanism for corrupting messages, as well as mechanisms to detect and cope with corrupted messages. In your solution, you may add new channels, variables, processes, change the type of messages, etc.

```
chan linkA = [5] of {byte};
chan linkB = [5] of {byte};
proctype sender ()
{ byte n;
do
:: n < 5 -> linkA!n*n; n++
:: n < 5 -> linkB!n*n; n++
:: else -> break
od
}
proctype receiver (chan link)
{ byte m, total;
do
:: link?m -> total=total+m
od
}
init
{
run sender (); run receiver (linkA);
run receiver (linkB)
}
```

Comment: 1. It is not clear whether you are authorized by your university/teacher to publish your assignment online, and whether using the solution provided by stranger does or not qualify as plagiarism according to the rules of your university 2. the scope of the exercise is unclear, because it does not specify the threat/validity model of the message exchange, nor how hard the system should try to avoid false negatives or false positives. The solution might range from something as simple as checking if the input value is the square number of something, or something as complex as [..continues..]

Comment: [..continues..] an handshake protocol and a convoluted checksum/ack system to avoid the type of smart corruption of messages that a *Man In The Middle* could perform.